# Materialize Navbar shows duplicate menu

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am copy>pasting this example code from Materialise.css
http://materializecss.com/navbar.html

The code shows a basic navbar, which is replaced by a mobile navbar on smaller screens. This works, except that in my 'normal' full window view, the navbar shows a duplicate menu.

In other words, the mobile `<ul></ul>` list is **not** hidden in the full window view.
What am I missing? (I included all the libraries, css, js, jquery, exactly as in the tutorial).

Materialize HTML:

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
      </ul>
      <!-- this should only show on mobile but it's also visible in full window view, resulting in two UL lists being shown -->
      <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
        <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

JQuery:

```
 $( document ).ready(function(){
   $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have [ghpages-materialize.css](http://materializecss.com/css/ghpages-materialize.css) is loaded in your code, from the example, it seems that the following CSS is responsible for hiding the mobile menu :

```
.side-nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 240px;
  left: -105%;
  top: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  height: calc(100% + 60px);
  height: -moz-calc(100%);
  padding-bottom: 60px;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 999;
  overflow-y: auto;
  will-change: left;
}
```

And it is found in the linked CSS.

Answer (score 0):

somethink like this?

```
if (menu1.legth > 0) {
    menu2.remove()
} else {
    menu1.remove()
}
```